# How to select row from from table if search by name in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Here is my screen shot of my output page.

I have been created drop down in which contains, 1.starts with 2.ends with and 3.contains.

I need to search record based on the above conditions.

I already created student table it has name,class,section,address,image and extra curricular.

Now i need to search record based if name contains,starts with and ends with.

For example if i select starts with in drop down and type "S" in the text box. It should show the record in which records name is starts with "S".

For that what should i do,? Can anyone guide me?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

code for searchrecord_click:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_searchedstudentrecords", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter retval = new SqlParameter("@condition", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                SqlParameter retval1 = new SqlParameter("@searchtext", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                com.Parameters.Add(retval);                
                string ReturnValue = retval.Value.ToString();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds);
                tblid.Visible = true;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Textemail.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilenum", Textmobilenum.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EC_id", Textcurricular.SelectedValue);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I confused with write stored procedure.

Comment: SDD (Stackoveflow Driven Development)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_searchedstudentrecords
@condition varchar(20),
@searchText varchar(10)
AS
if(@condition ='STARTS WITH')
SELECT * from tblStudents where NAME like @searchText+'%'
else if(@condition='Ends with')
SELECT * from tblStudents where NAME like '%'+@searchText
else
SELECT * from tblStudents where NAME like '%'+@searchText+'%'
```

Here is how you will call it and bind it to gridview

```
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("sp_searchedstudentrecords", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condition",condition);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchtext",searchtext);                
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
grdStudent.DataSource=ds.Tables[0];
grdStudent.DataBind();
```

You need to pass `condition` and `searchtext` from where you are calling this method.

Also you are using `mysql` so you will need to use `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataAdapter` instead of `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: how can i call these two parameters in my search_click? thanks

Comment: I updated my post. but i'm not sure it is correct.. can you please help me, thanks

Comment: @condition which was not supplied .. and may i know, what is USERNAME in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97853/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-rani).

Comment: so ..there is no need to write @name,@class...?

Answer (score 2):

Your querys must be:

For start with:

```
select name, section, class from students where name like @variable+'%'
```

For contains

```
select name, section, class from students where name like '%'+@variable+'%'
```

And finish with

```
select name, section, class from students where name like '%'+@variable
```

This three queries must be written into a IF-ELSE in a stored procedure.